# Custom Content-Type for File in Rails 'public' Folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For assets stored in the 'public' folder of a ruby-on-rails application is it possible to change the 'Content-Type' when running 'script/server'? For example, I am attempting to create an HTML5 application supporting offline mode, and have an 'offline.manifest'. When I run:

```
curl -I localhost:3000/offline.mainfest
```

The following header information is returned:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/plain
...
```

However, HTML5 specifications require:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/cache-manifest
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Rails 5, putting this in an initializer works:

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES[".manifest"]="text/cache-manifest"
```

I'm not sure about other versions.

n.b. that it will ***not*** work to do `Mime::Type.register "text/cache-manifest", :manifest` — this is only for rails controllers.

I'm not sure if `Rails::Rack::Static` is used anywhere in Rails. Rails uses `ActionDispatch::Static`, which doesn't inherit from `Rails::Rack::Static` or anything like that. But it does use several things from `Rack`, including `Rack::Mime`, which is (i think?) completely separate from `Mime` which is used elsewhere in Rails.

source for `ActionDispatch::Static`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I'd suggest digging into Rails::Rack::Static which is what serves files out of public these days.

Alternatively you could write a controller-action to serve just this filetype.
Serve them up using send_file and pass the type explicitly eg:

```
send_file params[:filename], :type => 'text/cache-manifest'
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the Rails::Rack::Static but ended up using the second option.