# Rails ignoring custom mime type

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My mime_types.rb file has

```
Mime::Type.register "application/myfoo", :myfoo
```

And I have a file `public/a/test.myfoo`

Browsing to `localhost:3000/a/test.myfoo` returns the file as `text/plain`.

I am using Chrome 22 and the Accept header is

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 with the development web server. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your controller the correspondent action looks something like this (I haven't tested it - just to give you a direction):

```
render :file => @somedir + "/test.myfoo", :content_type => Mime::myfoo
```

Specifically, the `:content_type` argument is the most important one.

Comment: There actually is no controller -- this is a static file in the public directory

Comment: Then you should create one. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646772/custom-content-type-for-file-in-rails-public-folder

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 5, putting this in an initializer works:

```
Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES[".manifest"]="text/cache-manifest"
```

I'm not sure about other versions.

`Mime::Type.register "text/cache-manifest", :manifest` is only for rails controllers.

source for `ActionDispatch::Static`: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb